# Tutorial for Spring Web Flow using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I want to develop a simple web application using Spring Web Flow. The project is essentially to getting hands-on on Spring Web Flow development. Can anyone guide me to a good tutorial for this development on Eclipse. I specifically need to do this on Eclipse so will be helpful to get tutorials pertaining to use of Eclipse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwN6UdDzZNA (MyEclipse-based but may be still useful)
- http://springinpractice.com/2008/05/05/build-a-shopping-cart-with-spring-web-flow-2-part-1/
- http://www.javabeat.net/2007/05/spring-web-flow-introduction/

Comment: Thanks for keeping the answer relevant!

Answer (score 3):

I've posted new video tutorial for beginners on how to setup Web Flow project Step by Step. Check it out on Youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnTTbu_6WH8

Description:
This part10 shows STEP by STEP Spring Webflow project setup + Hibernate + JSF + Spring project configuration in Eclipse STS + create test Flow and JSF view with Facelets and finally run test example on Tomcat server. Initial Maven project creation and adding libraries were covered in part 9.

Source code (revision 4):
http://code.google.com/p/jee-tutorial-youtube/source/browse/

Answer (score 0):

The example demonstrates using Web Flow to build a shopping cart wizard with a shipping rate subflow, decision states, service and data access Spring POJO beans, Spring 2.0 form tags, and a Web Flow FormAction bean for data binding, validation, and error reporting.

Use this link for the example : http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.x/reference/practical.html

The example breaks down its Spring application configuration into a number of files organized according to purpose. Although the example itself uses a small number of beans you may consider organizing a real-world application (with many more beans) according to similar principles.

Comment: Please do not include a 'signature' nor unrelated URLs in your post; it makes your post look like spam. I am editing the offending parts out so your legitimate answer can remain here.